# Does de-stigmatization of alcohol lead to less drunkenness?

Tags: alcohol

It is said (among those that I know) that allowing a minor to consume some alcohol actually encourages responsible behavior when older. The explanations vary, but most have concluded that the removal of the stigma removes the mysticism from the product and therefore decreases the desirability. This is followed by the argument that this will encourage the child to learn to drink responsibly in the home as opposed to in a less controlled environment.

---

I am aware of a relationship to [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2268/does-decriminalizing-drug-use-lead-to-less-drug-use), but that has to do with legality over illegality. I am more interested in stigma.

Comment: It's a common claim in countries where there is no drinking age.

Comment: @Sklivvz It is a common claim among those who wish to change the drinking age too.

Comment: Possible edit: I don't think "stigma" is the correct word for what is being defused (a "stigma" is a negative connotation). Just the opposite -- perhaps "romance" or "mystery."

Comment: @LarryOBrien They may be flip sides to the same coin, but as a parent, I am definitely curious about what effect my portraying alcohol in a negative light will have when my kids are old enough for it to matter.

Comment: @cwallenpoole maybe you can ask that on [parenting.SE]?

Comment: @Sklivvz Due respect to other parents, but this is exactly the type of thing which *should not* be asked on parenting -- it is extraordinarily difficult to get an objective opinion, let alone hard facts, on this topic, especially if someone's kids are involved.

Comment: "allowing a minor to consume some alcohol actually encourages responsible behavior when older." - What i have read suggested that demonstrating responsible behavior consistently as a parent was the effective strategy.  If you get drunk and act stupid even occasionally then the lesson your kid takes away that its OK to get drunk and act stupid.

Comment: Actually, the stigmatization of alcohol leads directly to pet shops filled with rambunctious yahoos and hot jazz music at 4 am. Make of it what you will:)

Comment: I don't use Yahoo, I use Google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this study, it's a poor strategy:

> Adult-supervised settings for alcohol use resulted in higher levels of harmful alcohol consequences, contrary to predictions derived from harm-minimization policy. Findings challenge the harm-minimization position that supervised alcohol use or early-age alcohol use will reduce the development of adolescent alcohol problems. (J. Stud. Alcohol Drugs, 72, 418–428, 2011)

[Influence of Family Factors and Supervised Alcohol Use on Adolescent Alcohol Use and Harms: Similarities Between Youth in Different Alcohol Policy Contexts](http://blog.seattlepi.com/thebigblog/files/2011/04/418-McMorris.pdf). McMorris et al.

I also found [this 2008 newspaper article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/3096757/Children-allowed-to-drink-at-home-more-likely-to-develop-alcohol-problems-study-suggests.html) that's clearly referring to a different study and which also warns against it. But I could not track down that study via the NIAA Website.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0899328997900092) might be the paper referenced.

Comment: I wonder whether there has ever been a decent meta-analysis of such studies. Last time I checked almost every study about alcohol policy was biased, poorly conducted or both. And I'm sure I've read exactly the opposite advice from a study.

Comment: Meh... I bet if they compared more than two countries the results would be less striking. In other countries without strict anti-drinking regulations (think Southern Europe), and with much less "pub culture" (think France, Italy) alcohol consumption is most often accompanied with food consumption. You don't go to the pub to get wasted on a few too many beers. You rather go to a "bar à vin" to taste some wine, and have some tapas with it. Or buy a nice bottle at a restaurant. It's not a matter of policy, it's more of a matter of the cultural approach to alcohol.